# Cortana skill translate or speech api

Tags: cortana-skills-kit

As Cortana supports a lot of cognitive api's I was hoping I could use the translate or bing speech api to record non-english text. I want to dictate text to Cortana that is not english and have her not interpret this but just pass it to the bot.

Is it possible to do this or somehow hook her up to bing speech or the speech translation API?

I know text translation is supported, but that does not help with Cortana botching up parts that are not English.

To be clear the app is in English but some user input provided is not (like an adress outside the US for example).

Answer (score 0):

Currently Cortana supports speech recognition for English language only. There is no way to hook up a bing speech API or any other API to perform speech recognition on Cortana's part.